# getting error while pushing project from xcode 6.2 to bitbucket

Tags: xcode, xcode6, push, bitbucket, git-push

I am getting following error while pushing whole project to bitbucket from xcode. [image: error]
I'm sure Im the only who is trying to pushing on a same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *pull* before you can *push*, as your local repo is not up-to-date.

The *pull* will merge remote changes into your local repo.

Comment: for doing this getting error '"origin/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from. Please choose a different remote branch.'

Comment: Sounds like the git repo isn't even configured correctly.